# virt-manager not working with X11 forwarding

Tags: linux, ssh, x11-forwarding, virt-manager

I'm trying to run virt-manager remotely on my mac and having problems. I'm using redhat 7.2 on a HP server. I've setup the following in my sshd file:

```
X11Forwarding yes 
X11DisplayOffset 10 
X11UseLocalhost no
```

Before I ssh, I run this in my terminal window:

```
jdurkin$ ssh -X admin@172.14.56.2 
jdurkin$ export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```

I do get these warning messages:

```
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated     
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
```

I've tried both -X and -Y.

Nothing happens after I type in virt-manager:

```
[root@Master1 ~]# virt-manager 
[root@Master1 ~]#
```

Then, these messages pops up:

```
[root@Master1 ~]# virt-manager 
[root@Master1 ~]# ** (virt-manager:25536): WARNING **: Could not open X display

(virt-manager:25536): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(virt-manager:25536): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_settings_get_style_cascade: assertion 'GTK_IS_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(virt-manager:25536): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(virt-manager:25536): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(virt-manager:25536): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(virt-manager:25536): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(virt-manager:25536): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(virt-manager:25536): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(virt-manager:25536): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed

(virt-manager:25536): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_rgba_value_get_rgba: assertion 'rgba->class == &GTK_CSS_VALUE_RGBA' failed
```

I don't know what else to try.

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: `jdurkin$ export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` don't do that.

Comment: when I do this, i do not get any response back.  just a blank line.  [admin@master] sudo virt-manager       [admin@master]$

Comment: `jdurkin$ export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` DON'T do that.

Comment: when I leave out export, I don't get a response.  just a blank line.

Comment: I changed export to export DISPLAY=<my mac ip address>:12:0.   I issued a echo $DISPLAY after ssh into server, and got back: 10.4.1.220:12:0.    I am still receiving same error messages.  no change.

Comment: If you have X server set up properly, you should have `DISPLAY` set by default correctly and you should not need to mess with that.